# My site cannot recognize my css file running ghost css script

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I register my css in Header with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css'; ?>">`

and the site couldn't recognize my css file, I also tried to use enqueue style :

```
function my_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array( 'style' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_assets' );
```

and it recognize the css but when you edit the css file it is not changing/updating, so I deleted the *enqueue_style* function and now it recognizes 2 css and still not changing when you edit the css file.

[image]

what do you think is the problem and solution here?

Comment: Browser caching, maybe? Or do you have some plugin for asset compression in WP that might be doing its own caching?

Comment: I only have, defender pro, forminator pro, branda, revslider etc. but I think i don't have any plugin for cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use versioning when you enqueue the file.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css'), false );
```

On the official documentation, you can check the version parameters i used on this sample:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Hope it helps.

Jose